# JMeter: How to know why my regular expression extractor in JMeter is not extracting the data

Tags: regex, testing, parameters, load, jmeter

I would like to know why regular expression extractor in JMeter is not extracting the data after parameterization. **Response message: Internal Server Error**

**Expression added are:**

1. name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.+?)"
2. name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+?)"

```html
POST data:
__VIEWSTATE=%24%7BviewState%7D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%24%7BeventValidation%7D&txtUserID=1001201&txtPWD=CFL&BtnSubmit=Submit&hdnE=5&hdnN=323&hdnD=173
```

Comment: Please add actual expressions and the errors you're facing. I can't comprehend the images considering that most of the content is redacted.

Comment: Added. There are no such error apart from Internal Server Error. Also, Post data that is getting send is "${viewState}" and "${eventValidation}" which I can see in HTTP under Request in View Results in a Tree.

Comment: can you show a response containing the 2 parameters ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp is probably wrong.

To debug it, run your test then use View Results Tree and select Regexp Tester:

[image]

You can then test your regexps and see what happens.

As I don't have the response content that contains the 2 tokens, I can only guess that regexp should be :

- name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="([^"]+?)" , see https://regex101.com/r/aG1gX2/1
- name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([^"]+?)" , see https://regex101.com/r/iM5cZ3/1

Comment: Just in case you have some insight Ubik: I have the exact same issue as the OP.  I am using your RegExp Tester advice, and it works (it finds the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION inputs).  Yet I am still sending the (escaped) literal value "${viewstate}" when I post back instead of the desired value. Any idea why this would not work?  I've seen dozens of posts on this, and every one has the same advice on capturing these hidden inputs.

Comment: Can you ask a new question with screenshots of where you put your regex ? Thanks

Comment: Done @UBIK_LOAD_PACK, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672771/regular-expression-extractor-failing-in-jmeter-for-asp-net-web-forms