# Viewstate Replacing error. [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. ]

Tags: regex, jmeter, viewstate

Tried with [JMeter: How to know why my regular expression extractor in JMeter is not extracting the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797774/jmeter-how-to-know-why-my-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter-is-not-extract) but still not able to replace my view-state,  its throwing  [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. ] error . Please check the attachment , an my script has not _EVENTVALIDATION .
enter image description here[Viewstate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DovTB.png)

[viwstate2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhKRB.png)

Comment: Please share your  own problem statement. Currently, you question is very vague. Cannot understand it!

Answer (score 0):

As i am observing from your attached image

```
You need to pass same `Reference name` as a value of __VIEWSTATE in Next request
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First Cross verify, Is your correaltion is correct or not? (you can use debug sampler to check the correlation)

If yes, then first mistake is, you had given reference name as "VIEWSTATE" in below shown snapshot[image]

But you are passing ${jsfViewState} in other snapshot, so correct it and pass same reference name i.e. `${VIEWSTATE}`

It'll resolve your issue, if issue still persists then click on encode button beside Name-Value pair because sometimes there is some mismatch in encoding format between the response which we capture and the value which we have to pass
[image]

Comment: Tried with both option with encoding and without encoding but meter through error , [INVALID Viewstate]

Comment: have you changed value to ${VIEWSTATE} also

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused with [ASP.NET ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) and [JSF Viewstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910741/what-is-viewstate-in-jsf-and-how-is-it-used), they have similar nature but different underlying technologies and different parameter names

Given you correctly correlated the value, I believe you need to change `__VIEWSTATE` parameter name to `javax.faces.ViewState` and it should work.

See [Testing a JSF Application with JMeter](https://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter) guide for a little bit more detailed explanation on the topic and [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for some troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: appreciate your answer, view-state error has been resolved but still my response not increasing.Please check with my new question  '' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35721769/regular-expressionn-not-able-to-correlate-my-test-scenario-with-viewsate-in-jmet '' explanied the scenario.