# regular expressionn not able to correlate my test scenario with viewsate in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, viewstate

[image: viewstate value][image]I have tried with regular expression also with css/j query extractor,not able to run my script properly.
My exact test scenario is kind of

1. There is kind of application form.
2. First Load the page.
3. Fill with some data, then go to next page.
4. Now again fill some details, and Submit.

Note:For Each and every 'application form' there is two "9" digit unique number , which gets generated from server side, and after participating the form there is two options:
a)Access Count
b)Response Count

Every time J meter thread group hits the page 'Access count' properly gets increased , but Response Count not gets change, it should get increase for each user as well.
I have tries to correlate both the parameter using regular expression and css/j query expression , but still the 'Response Count' not gets increment. What should I do for this case to do Load test in J meter.
[Viewstate regular expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCFgE.png)
[Change parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4hOB.png)

Regular Expression: input[id=_VIEWSTATE]

While Checking the response data in

> result tree its showing different in Load page and next Page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) as a child of the **first** request.
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: VIEWSTATE
   - Regular Expression: `<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="([^"]+)".*/>`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. Refer extracted value as `${VIEWSTATE}` where required.

By the way, you can test your Regular Expressions right in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener using RegExp Tester view.

Comment: I have passed the Regular Expression as :"" <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([^"]+)".*/> "" , as  "<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="([^"]+)".*/>" it was showing 0 Match found 'View Tree Result' 'Regx Expression Tester' . But still Im getting the output as "Invalid Viewstate" in output from "View Tree Result" 'Response Output'.

Comment: [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. Client IP: ..*.* Port: 57119 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0 ViewState: ${__VIEWSTATE} Referer: http://*.com/*.aspx?k=RQsQPSRVsRTQsPsPsP&amp;lang=0&amp;data= Path: /blank.aspx] ================================ [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. Client IP: Port: 58055 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0 ViewState: ${__VIEWSTATE} Referer: http://**.com/*.aspx?k=RQsQPSRVsRTQsPsPsP&amp;lang=0&amp;data= Path: /blank.aspx]

Comment: Well, it is .NET, not Java, screenshot explains a lot. In fact your original `input[id=__VIEWSTATE]` expression was fine, but it has to go to [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor). And put `value` into "Attribute` field. See  [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for details.

Comment: And mind the double underscore. It is `__VIEWSTATE`, not `_VIEWSTATE`

Comment: Dmitri I have checked out the blog too but still not solving that issue. Should I give you the Link of my application so that you can check .

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression is wrong.
input[id=_VIEWSTATE]  can' t capture a value.
You can test it in regular expression tester of response.

It may be something like: input[id=(.*?)]
It depends on your dynamic value. But in question you didnt mention screenshot of that dyanamic data.

Comment: added images for dynamic value plz check

Comment: Actually I meant screen shot of response where you are seeing the viewstate. So that we can get the correct regular expression.You can also verify that.You can see regular expression tester option for response.There you can test your regular expression and verify you are getting the expected values.

Comment: If you go through this example with screenshots  you will clearly understand: http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html

Comment: have added the view-state value

Comment: No still not working, the main concern is while each thread submmiting the form , then that 'Response Count' should increase accordingly .

Comment: Use, id="VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" as regular ecpression and use template $1$ and check match.

Comment: while putting the syntax named "<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([^"]+)".*/>" in 'result view tree' regx expression tester , it gives 1 matches, but while running the script it does through the error named "Invalid Viewstate"

Comment: Where are you adding the reg ecp extractor, in the previous request na? Means extractor shoul be in rqst having this response and you have to use the variable in nect request.

Comment: To check the value during run add a debug sampler from samplers and check the value of viewstate variable.By this way yiu can know whatvalue is actully coming.

Comment: [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
 Client IP: *.*.*.*
 Port: 57119
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
 ViewState: ${__VIEWSTATE}
 Referer: http://*.com/*.aspx?k=RQsQPSRVsRTQsPsPsP&amp;lang=0&amp;data=
 Path: /blank.aspx]
================================
[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
 Client IP: 
 Port: 58055
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
 ViewState: ${__VIEWSTATE}
 Referer: http://**.com/*.aspx?k=RQsQPSRVsRTQsPsPsP&amp;lang=0&amp;data=
 Path: /blank.aspx]

Comment: Use debug sampler and verify the value. Here it is showing as variable is not replaced. Why you are giving ${_viewstate} ? Is that variable name correct? In regular rxp extractor you used reference name as 'viewstate' then you shuld use ${viewstate} while passing.No need of _viewstate.

Comment: Kept the same name as Refference name and avriable value.But still getting that Invalid Viewstate Error . And I have used Debug Sampler but not able to get the meaning of "Jmeter Properties > True/False" , "Jmeter variable > True/False" , "System  Properties > True/False" . Kindly clarify that .

Comment: You just add debug sampler and then after run, in view result tree you can see one debug sampler response with the values of all variables(choose text mode to see).There you can find value of viewstate.

Comment: Yes Im getting the viewstate value, but every time I run the script the value changes , but while I put regular expression it gives Invalid View-state .