# Regular Expression Extractor failing in JMeter for asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, jmeter, viewstate

Using JMeter, I'm attempting to log in to an asp.net web forms application. I recorded the login sequence to a *.jmx file, and now I'm attempting to extract the __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION hidden inputs using the Regular Expression Extractor post-processor.

In all 3 cases JMeter is extracting the name of the variable that I want to extract into (eg "${viewstate}") instead of the value I want to extract.  Here is what the RequestBody looks like when I look at the ViewResults Tree and select "Text":

ReturnUrl=%2F&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=%24%7Bviewstategenerator%7D&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%24%7Bviewstate%7D&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24LoginButton.x=25&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24Password=MyPassword%21&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24LoginButton.y=4&__LASTFOCUS=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24UserName=MyUserName&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%24%7Beventvalidation%7D

Oddly enough, if I select "RegExpTester" in the ViewResults Tree and test my regular expressions, all of them appear to work.

For example, here is what my __VIEWSTATE extractor looks like:

[image]

The Regular Expression is this bit of text:

```
name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+?)"
```

When I enter that expression into the RegExp Tester it finds it.  The other 2 also work:

[image]

This is my first time using JMeter, I suspect I've got something in the wrong place.

Here is how my HTTP Request is set up:

[image]

Here is how the entire project looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you expect these values to come from? You're missing one [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request which will open the login page, your test should not start from [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request.

Once you execute GET request - your Regular Expression extractors will capture viewstate and friends and you will be able to log in.

Also consider switching to [CSS Selector Extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)  as [using regular expressions to parse HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748).

The relevant CSS Selector expression would be as simple as `input[id=__VIEWSTATE]`, use `value` as the attribute. Similarly correlate remaining dynamic values. See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for more details if needed.